# Where can I find a SVN application that will display the whole tree (or branch) graphically as a map

Tags: svn, user-interface

Due to some bad practices regarding branching within a project in work, I am looking for an application that I can point at a subversion server and produce a map that will graphically outline the rats nest that exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Liam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Windows, does the [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) revision graph not do what you want?

Comment: Also note that the TortoiseSVN revision graph was overhauled for the 1.6 release, so be sure to upgrade first.

Comment: +1, I've just done this myself for some of our projects, and looking at 1.6's revision graph just now, wish I'd waited for this to be released.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I upgraded to the latest version of tortoiseSVN and tried the graph but it kept timing out. I'm guessing that this is a 1.6 server specific feature?  (We're running 1.1.4 - separate problem!!!) It did, however work with https://svn.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try `svn ls -R` for a command-line version. Not terribly graphical, though.

Answer (score 0):

More cross-platform solution is to use
svn-graph.pl (http://subversion.tigris.org/tools_contrib.html#svn_graph_pl) 
with GraphViz (http://www.graphviz.org/)

Some assembly likely required.